# Do I GPG-sign my application before or after packaging?

Tags: application-development, packaging, launchpad, gnupg

I am almost ready to complete my app, but I am unclear on the sequence of packing a completed app, and getting it uploaded so users of the software center can find it for installing.

Does the signing of the files with a GPG key have to be done to just the `debian/` directory, or do I have to use a `quickly` command to upload it and it is then signed on Launchpad?

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to ensure you have your GPG installed on Launchpad. Details of how to set this up are at https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/ImportingYourPGPKey - this only takes a few minutes to set up.

When you have your GPG in place you are in a position to put a package in a PPA on Launchpad.

If you just want to generate a package and install it on your computer, you can do this by running `quickly` package (presuming you are using Quickly).

If you are not running Quickly just run `dpkg-buildpackage` when you have configured your packaging (Quickly automates this).

To publish to the PPA run `quickly release` (this will require that your GPG key is already set up).

Comment: For general PPA uploads, `debuild -s -s{a|d}` is the final step (including signing), *not* dpkg-buildpackage which will build and sign your package binaries locally. (Launchpad, atleast for PPAs, wants your source, not debs)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer: that is exactly what i needed to know.